# html base and subdirectories

Tags: html, hyperlink

In my html I have

```
<head>
 <base href="http://mydomain.com/dev/">
</head>
```

But my links all go to mydomain.com/ (without the "dev" subfolder). Why aren't my links pointing to the subfolder?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
my link html is:

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
  <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/realestate.html">Real Estate</a></li>
  <li><a href="/property.html">Vehicles &amp; Boats</a></li>
  <li><a href="/location.html">Auction Locations</a></li>
  <li><a href="/auctionDetails.html">How the Auction Works</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact.html" class="activeTab">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Again, thanks.

Comment: How about posting the HTML of some of your links?

Comment: Yeah Please post a HTML of your links

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using root relative URIs (`<a href="/foo">`) instead of document relative URIs (`<a href="foo">`).

Resolution will start from `http://example.com/dev/` but the `/` will cause the local part (everything after the domain/port number) to be dropped.

Do not start your links with a `/` character.