# Can I use a relative path as the base tag's href value?

Tags: html

Is there any way to define a base link for a web page, meaning that all relative hrefs in the page start at that base location (different from the location of the web page)?

This is what I want:

```
<base = "../Main/Sub/Subsub1/">
```

The page I'm using this in is in a subfolder parallel to Main, but the content it will link to is under Main.  I tried the above code, but it doesn't work

Comment: Any example of how it looks like now and how it should look like would be great!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve. All this would do is save some href length in your anchors.

Comment: True - it's not a huge deal.  Just wondering if there was a way.

Comment: @thf try the answer below to see if it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why base tag does not work for relative paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521011/why-base-tag-does-not-work-for-relative-paths)

Comment: You better refer the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351944/html-base-and-subdirectories

Comment: I looked at that, but I didn't work with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `js` to generate the base url as below

```
<script>
var base = document.createChild('base');
// use logic to do ../
base.href = window.location.href.split('/').slice(0,-1).join('/')+'/Main/Sub/Subsub1/';
document.head.appendChild(base);
</script>
```

Or provide the absolute url to base `href`

> The HTML  element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs in a document. There can be only one  element in a document.

Refer the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Comment: Thanks - but I was looking for a way that didn't use js.

Comment: provide absolute url, js is used to create information that you don't provide directly